# Begin with A, B, C

Tags: crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**1** A Hebrew letter
**4** A franchise in various cities
**7** Staggers from South Dakota
**12** Muslim group in China
**13** Fishy
**14** Some woodwinds
**15** An Oxonian college: *2 words*
**17** Food from the sky
**18** A small but heavily studied people of India
**19** Devotee
**21** Occupies a throne
**23** Fuss
**24** Hungarian sheepdog
**27** Version
**30** A sausage
**31** A quasibiographical play and film: *4 words*
**34** An unbribable federal agent
**35** Where magical creatures live
**36** Where to display one's stock
**37** Set
**38** ____ we change the clocks?: *2 words*
**41** Mark one's place: *hyph.*
**44** A Hebrew month
**45** Not: *2 words*
**48** Nerves
**50** No problem: *2 words*
**51** Bloom County interjection
**52** A string instrument
**53** Keep an ____ …: *2 words*
**54** Piglet friend
**55** A trisomy

#### Down

**1** ____ you doin'?
**2** Ancient Greek woodwinds
**3** Greylags: *2 words*
**4** The largest public uni. system in the U.S.
**5** Many an early antibiotic
**6** Mag. identifier
**7** An island known for its dragons
**8** Auction site
**9** Harry's mate
**10** Appearance
**11** U.S. DHS div.
**16** Schmucks: *hyph.*
**20** A Canadian ski destination
**22** Home of the Salukis: *abbr.*
**24** A dance with a partner: *3 words*
**25** A river in the book of Daniel
**26** Parody
**28** Search-by-image pioneer
**29** A German mouthwash
**30** Panama, for example: *2 words*
**31** It's used to knock down bldgs.
**32** At hand
**33** LL.M. alternative
**37** *… from the Black ____*
**39** Irritable
**40** Jack of Twitter
**41** One of the first games implicated in the game-show scandal
**42** Unlocked
**43** The Teflon Don got stuck on it
**45** A Greek dairy brand
**46** *As ____ Dying*: *2 words*
**47** A msg. received back well after it's sent
**49** One way to end a boxing match: *abbr.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That was harder than it first appeared, with several apparently contradictory answers, until I realised:

> that the A,B,C of the title is a reference to musical notes, and a hint that we when we find a [Solfege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge) note name (Do, Re, Mi, etc.) in an answer, it should be entered in a single square.

The completed grid:

> [image]

The answers:

> 1 A Hebrew letter - **WAW**
>  4 A franchise in various cities - **CSI**
>  7 Staggers from South Dakota - **KERMIT** ([Kermit Staggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_Staggers))
>  12 Muslim group in China - **HUI**
>  13 Fishy - **SUS**(picious)
>  14 Some woodwinds - **OBOES**
>  15 An Oxonian college: 2 words - **ALL SOULS**
>  17 Food from the sky - **MANNA** (... from heaven)
>  18 A small but heavily studied people of India - **TODA**
>  19 Devotee - **FANBOY**
>  21 Occupies a throne - **REIGNS**
>  23 Fuss - **ADO**
>  24 Hungarian sheepdog - **PUMI**
>  27 Version - **EDITION**
>  30 A sausage - **SALAMI**
>  31 A quasibiographical play and film: 4 words - **THE SOUND OF MUSIC**
>  34 An unbribable federal agent - **NESS** ([Eliot Ness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliot_Ness))
>  35 Where magical creatures live - **ELFLAND**
>  36 Where to display one's stock - **TREE**
>  37 Set - **LAY**
>  38 ____ we change the clocks?: 2 words - **WHEN DO**
>  41 Mark one's place: hyph. - **DOG-EAR** (turn the corner of a page)
>  44 A Hebrew month - **ADAR**
>  45 Not: 2 words - **FAIL TO**
>  48 Nerves - **JITTERS**
>  50 No problem: 2 words - **GLAD TO**
>  51 Bloom County interjection - **ACK**
>  52 A string instrument - **UKE**
>  53 Keep an ____ …: 2 words - **EYE ON**
>  54 Piglet friend - **ROO**
>  55 A trisomy - **XYY**
>
>  Down
>  1 ____ you doin'? - **WHAT'RE**
>  2 Ancient Greek woodwinds - **AULOI**
>  3 Greylags: 2 words - **WILD GEESE**
>  4 The largest public uni. system in the U.S. - **CSU** ([California State University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_University) claims to be the largest, but on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_universities_and_university_networks_by_enrollment) it appears below University System of Ohio.
>  5 Many an early antibiotic - **SULFA** ([Sulfonamide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfonamide_(medicine)))
>  6 Mag. identifier - **ISSN** (International Standard Serial Number)
>  7 An island known for its dragons - **KOMODO**
>  8 Auction site - **EBAY**
>  9 Harry's mate - **RON** (no idea who this is, just filled in by crossing letters)
>  10 Appearance - **MIEN**
>  11 U.S. DHS div. - **TSA**
>  16 Schmucks: hyph. - **SO-AND-SOS**
>  20 A Canadian ski destination - **BANFF**
>  22 Home of the Salukis: abbr. - **SIU** ([Southern Illinois University](https://siusalukis.com/))
>  24 A dance with a partner: 3 words - **PAS DE DEUX**
>  25 A river in the book of Daniel - **ULAI**
>  26 Parody - **MIMIC**
>  28 Search-by-image pioneer - **TIN EYE**
>  29 A German mouthwash - **ODOL**
>  30 Panama, for example: 2 words - **SUN HAT**
>  31 It's used to knock down bldgs. - **TNT**
>  32 At hand - **HERE**
>  33 LL.M. alternative - **M.LAW**
>  37 … from the Black ____ - **LAGOON** (The creature ...)
>  39 Irritable - **NARKY**
>  40 Jack of Twitter - **DORSEY**
>  41 One of the first games implicated in the game-show scandal - [**DOTTO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotto#Scandal_and_cancellation)
>  42 Unlocked - **AJAR**
>  43 The Teflon Don got stuck on it - **RICO** ("Teflon Don" is [John Gotti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gotti))
>  45 A Greek dairy brand - **FAGE**
>  46 As ____ Dying: 2 words - **I LAY**
>  47 A msg. received back well after it's sent - **LDE** ([Long Delayed Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_delayed_echo))
>  49 One way to end a boxing match: abbr. - **TKO** (Technical Knockout)

Comment: Well done. Note also that the title of the puzzle is a line from [this song](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-Re-Mi); cf. 31 Across.

Comment: for 9D, that's a *Harry Potter* reference.