# Begin with A, B, C (again!)

Tags: crosswords

Er, wait a moment... This grid and title both seem very familiar... (*Puzzle inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123279/begin-with-a-b-c) by [msh210](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/93/msh210).*)

[image]

#### Across

**1** Obamacare: *abbr.*
**4** Taxi
**7** Ethiopian capital, Addis _____
**12** Father of Odin
**13** 2001 Will Smith movie
**14** 46<sup>th</sup> President of the US
**15** Gave an excuse for
**17** In a line matching the direction of (something)
**18** Thick heavy weapon
**19** Stop
**21** Caper
**23** Exist
**24** Television reality game show: *abbr.*
**27** Tapering medieval dagger
**30** Jeddah-based professional football team, Al-____
**31** Series of aerial attacks on English cities in WWII: *2 words*
**34** 'To him', in French: *2 words*
**35** Dutch city
**36** K-pop group ('Dynamite'): *abbr.*
**37** Element with atomic number 24
**38** Robotic humanoid, presenter of Channel 4's 2022 Alternative Christmas message
**41** Japanese city
**44** Dry
**45** Monastery
**48** Amino acid
**50** Cook
**51** Nevertheless
**52** US requirement for operating large or heavy vehicles
**53** George _____, English logician
**54** Loudspeaker
**55** Yes

#### Down

**1** Banana species
**2** Punctuation mark
**3** Greek god of beekeeping
**4** IATA code for Egypt's largest airport: *abbr.*
**5** 'Smart' chap?
**6** Wait calmly
**7** Belittle or degrade
**8** Bodily fluid
**9** Fuss
**10** Scottish mountain
**11** ___ Lee, movie director
**16** Okra
**20** Communist League of America founder, Marty _____
**22** Cavaliers?: *abbr.*
**24** The interrelated elements of two global powerhouse economies
**25** Popular sandwich: *abbr.*
**26** Entertainment business?
**28** Grid-deduction puzzle genre
**29** IATA code for Cherbourg airport: *abbr.*
**30** 'German', in Spanish
**31** Friendly form of address in the English West Midlands
**32** Computer key
**33** UK equestrian sports regulator
**37** Bodily fluid
**39** _____ Crawford, US model and actress
**40** Mononymous singer-songwriter
**41** Plaster a roof
**42** ____ Yaga, character of Slavic folklore
**43** KAl(SO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>·12 H<sub>2</sub>O
**45** Duane and Gregg's group?: *abbr.*
**46** Frat boy?
**47** "Surprise!"
**49** Cellular energy source: *abbr.*

Comment: Here's the [Penpa+ grid](https://tinyurl.com/bdds2r62) I created for the previous puzzle if anyone wants a copy

Comment: Thanks @fljx - that's really helpful :)

Comment: Awesome. You didn't use 'bacchanal' though, aw...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Final completed crossword:

> [image]
>
> And based off the title, every single word begins with either an A, B or C!
>
> In fact, as @DanielS noted below, the letters A, B and C *only* appear in the grid at the start of the words!

---

And answers to the clues:

Across:

> 1 Obamacare: abbr. **ACA**
> 4 Taxi **CAB**
> 7 Ethiopian capital, Addis _____ **ABABA**
> 12 Father of Odin **BOR**
> 13 2001 Will Smith movie **ALI**
> 14 46th President of the US **BIDEN**
> 15 Gave an excuse for **ALIBIED**
> 17 In a line matching the direction of (something) **ALONG**
> 18 Thick heavy weapon **COSH**
> 19 Stop **CEASE**
> 21 Caper **ANTIC**
> 23 Exist **BE**
> 24 Television reality game show: abbr.  **CBB**
> 27 Tapering medieval dagger **ANLACE**
> 30 Jeddah-based professional football team, Al-____ **AHLI**
> 31 Series of aerial attacks on English cities in WWII: 2 words **BAEDEKER BLITZ**
> 34 'To him', in French: 2 words **A LUI**
> 35 Dutch city **ARNHEM**
> 36 K-pop group ('Dynamite'): abbr. **BTS**
> 37 Element with atomic number 24  **CR** (Chromium)
> 38 Robotic humanoid, presenter of Channel 4's 2022 Alternative Christmas message **AMECA**
> 41 Japanese city **CHIBA**
> 44 Dry **ARID**
> 45 Monastery **ABBEY**
> 48 Amino acid **ALANINE**
> 50 Cook **BROIL**
> 51 Nevertheless **BUT**
> 52 US requirement for operating large or heavy vehicles **CDL**
> 53 George _____, English logician **BOOLE**
> 54 Loudspeaker **AMP**
> 55 Yes **AYE**

Down:

> 1 Banana species **ABACA**
> 2 Punctuation mark **COLON**
> 3 Greek god of beekeeping **ARISTAEUS**
> 4 IATA code for Egypt's largest airport: abbr. **CAI**
> 5 'Smart' chap? **ALEC**
> 6 Wait calmly **BIDE**
> 7 Belittle or degrade **ABASE**
> 8 Bodily fluid **BILE**
> 9 Fuss **ADO**
> 10 Scottish mountain **BEN**
> 11 ___ Lee, movie director **ANG**
> 16 Okra **BHINDI**
> 20 Communist League of America founder, Marty _____ **ABERN**
> 22 Cavaliers?: abbr. **CLE**
> 24 The interrelated elements of two global powerhouse economies **CHIMERICA**
> 25 Popular sandwich: abbr. **BLT**
> 26 Entertainment business?  **BIZ**
> 28 Grid-deduction puzzle genre **AKARI**
> 29 IATA code for Cherbourg airport: abbr. **CER**
> 30 'German', in Spanish **ALEMAN**
> 31 Friendly form of address in the English West Midlands **BAB**
> 32 Computer key **ALT**
> 33 UK equestrian sports regulator **BHA**
> 37 Bodily fluid **CHYLE**
> 39 _____ Crawford, US model and actress **CINDY**
> 40 Mononymous singer-songwriter **ADELE**
> 41 Plaster a roof **CEIL**
> 42 ____ Yaga, character of Slavic folklore **BABA**
> 43 KAl(SO4)2·12 H2O **ALUM**
> 45 Duane and Gregg's group?: abbr. **ABB**
> 46 Frat boy? **BRO**
> 47 "Surprise!" **BOO**
> 49 Cellular energy source: abbr. **ATP**

Comment: Concerning your remark at the end of the first spoiler block: Not only that!

Comment: @MOehm d'oh! Not sure how I missed that :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil ...and furthermore the constraint is if and only if.

Comment: This is the correct completed grid, and - as alluded to by Daniel above - you also won't spot any of these 'characters' outside their numbered cages :)

Comment: @Stiv ooh nice extra touch, added!

Comment: I don’t know if it’s because I’m on a Mac or what, but some keys don’t work when typing answers. For example, C, Y, and Z.

Comment: Today I learned, that a hyperbolic function is apparently equivalent to a thick heavy weapon.